# How to sort a file list in reverse order but not in descending? sort -r does not work what I want

Tags: linux

I have the following command

```
cat filename
```

Output:

```
0040
0042
0048
0043
```

If I do `cat filename | sort -r` the output is:

```
0048
0043
0042
0040
```

I dont want that; it looks its sorting in descending order instead of in reverse order.

I want the following output (A true reverse order)

```
0043
0048
0042
0040
```

How can I do that?

Comment: It sounds like you want `tac` ("reverse cat") rather than a _sort_.  Reversing a file isn't sorting.

Answer (score 11):

To reverse a file, use [`tac`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tac.1.html):

```
tac filename
```

`sort -r` doesn’t do what you’re after because it doesn’t reverse, it sorts in reverse order; that’s why you end up with the numbers in decreasing order (although you shouldn’t think of them as numbers here, since the default sort is lexicographic).

Answer (score 2):

You should really use [`tac`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/493964/90751), but you *could* do this using `sort -r`, if you prefix each line with its own number, and numerically sort those.   You'll have to cut the line numbers off again afterwards.

```
cat filename | nl | sort -n -r | cut -f 2-
```

This will not work for all input: `nl` will skip blank lines, and also looks for "sections", delimited by lines containing only (multiples of) the string `\:`.  You'd have to use `-ba` to handle the blank lines, and change the section delimiter with `-d XZ`, to any 2-character sequence that doesn't appear alone on a line.

Comment: This will mess up blank lines; you need to add `-ba` to `nl` to avoid that. It will also get messed up by section separators (`\:` by default).

Comment: @StephenKitt Rats, the `nl` spec doesn't even permit "no section delimiters" either.  Updated.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching and found two useful answers; one is just using `tac` at the end and the other is an `awk` statement in which I don't understand!

Answer 1: `cat filename | tac`

Answer 2: `cat filename | awk '{arr[i++]=$0} END {while (i>0) print arr[--i] }'`

Just wondering why the `sort -r` didnt worked!..

Comment: Because `sort`ing (even with `-r`) is not the same as reverting the current order. `sort`ing arranges lines by value - be that ASCII or numeric.

Comment: FYI: You generally don't need `cat` to feed a file into a "filter" program like `tac` or `awk`. Just pass the file name to the filter, like `tac filename`.